# How to correctly import a Maven dependency that I altered and re-built into an existing project?

Tags: maven, jar, log4j2, pulsar

I have a Maven dependency, [pulsar-log4j2-appender](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/tree/master/pulsar-log4j2-appender), which I forked and changed the source code because it was throwing exceptions in my project.

After changing the source code, I ran the maven `package` command to build the jar and imported it into my project (in Intellij: `Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies | Add JARs or directories...)`.

However, when I run the application, it seems like it's not able to find that dependency because the Pulsar appender which I declared in my log4j2.xml file isn't being configured.

Am I importing the JAR properly? I'm wondering if the JAR needs to be within the `org.apache.pulsar` namespace to be imported properly.

For example,

This is what the dependency looks like unaltered:

[image]

And this is what it looks like when I modify and build it myself:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the code from an open source project you should change both the groupId and the artifact id.  If you do not you will have problems and future developers will say your name in ways you do not want to hear.

Changing these are necessary so that Maven knows to use your version instead of the publicly available version. Also, when people look at your project and see the groupId and artifactId from the "real" project they will naturally assume that is what is being used (which is why they will curse you if that is not the case). In addition, you will have to do something convoluted to get Maven to use your dependency reliably.

The practice I have followed is the prepend "com.mycorp", where mycorp is my employer's name, to the groupId and add mycorp into the artifactId. The only downside to this is that you must ensure that the "real" artifact's coordinates are not referenced as a dependency or as a transitive dependency or else you will have duplicate classes on the class path.

Finally, your best bet is to create a pull request for Apache Pulsar with your fix so that other people experiencing the same problem you are get the benefit of it.